# Server 400 error when beautifying URLs within the Yii Framework

Tags: url, url-rewriting, yii

so, using urlManager i've been able to get to this point:

```
'people/<id:\d+>/<last:.*?>/<name:.*?>'=>'person/view',
```

which generates this: http://foo.com/people/3/smith/john

I want to eliminate the ID number, which in this case is "3"

I tried using this:

```
'people/<last:.*?>/<name:.*?>'=>'person/view', //makes sense right?
```

however, when i try to navigate to http://foo.com/people/smith/john , I get a server 400 error. 
What gives? Should I try modifying the .htaccess file instead?

As requested here is my entire urlManager component:

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            'about' => array('site/page', 'defaultParams' => array('view' => 'about')),
            'contact'=>'site/contact',
            'login' =>'site/login',
            '/'=>'site/index',
            'people/<last:.*?>/<name:.*?>'=>'person/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

Here is my PersonController.php file:

```
public function actionView()
{
    $person=$this->loadModel();
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$person,
    ));
}

private $_model;

public function loadModel()
{
    if($this->_model===null)
    {
        if(isset($_GET['last']))
        {
            $this->_model=Person::model()->findByPk($_GET['id']);
        }
        if($this->_model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    }
    return $this->_model;
}
```

Comment: There appears to be a typo in your second rule. It is identical to the first. Additionally, it would help if you pasted the entire contents of your urlManager component so we can see which rules supersede which. This should be pretty easy to sort out.

Comment: you're right, i did have a typo, i edited my question to reflect that

Comment: Are you sure it's 400 and not 500? In either case, do you have access to your server logs to see what the error is?

Comment: yep, it's definitely 400. error log says nothing, except for a few php syntax errors i committed earlier today.

Comment: Just grasping at straws here, try the following: Move the most general rule '/' down to the bottom. Change the stars in that rule to plus signs. And change the dots to `\w`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view action needs to accept the names and do a find by the attributes instead of using loadModel, which requires the ID:

```
public function actionView($last, $name)
{
    $person = Person::model()->find(
        'name=":name" AND last=":last"',
        array(':name'=>$name, ':last'=>$last)
    );

    if($person === null) throw new CHttpException(404);

    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$person,
    ));
}
```

Do note that your request will not support multiple people with same first and last names!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a rewrite condition for URLs so requests are still routed back to index.php.

check out this guide: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#user-friendly-urls

Answer (score 0):

look at the `actionView` of the `PersonController`

```
public function actionView($id,...)
{

}
```

So the view action must need an `$id` parameter for it to work. Otherwise it throws a 400 bad request error. In your modified url rule the only parameters specified are `$last` and `$name`. The solution is to remove the `$id` parameter to `actionView()` if it is not used inside `actionView`. Otherwise you have to change function logic for determining the required person from `$last` and `$name` instead of `$id`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I'm getting closer, but it's still escaping me. I removed $id from both actionView() and loadModel(), but I can't get it to work without using $_GET['id']. I've added what I have to my Question.

Comment: as i already stated you can only load a person model if you know the id(the primary key). In your modified url there is no id parameter. So you got two options. Either retain the id in the url or change the loadmodel with lastname. For the second method the last name must be unique ie no two persons have same last name which is practically imposible.